# Windows 8 Native App in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: windows-8, asp.net

I was not sure if this should be here or stackoverflow. I am looking at developing some windows 8 apps. I come from a web background and was really intrigued that you make them with html and javascript.

I started to think though why can't you use asp.net mvc to build a windows 8 application.

My question is can you somehow use asp.net mvc to build a native windows 8 application or are you suck with javascript and html?

Answer (score 1):

Building an asp.net application requires a webserver like IIS to execute the code.
The kind of [application you're talking about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx) is built with *javascript* as a programming language just like you said - you cannot mix the 2.

You could of course use a remote webserver to handle your asp.net MVC app, but it'd leave your "local" windows 8 app as an empty webview.

**TL;DR**
You can't make an app running with *local* asp.net code.

Comment: Hmm ya I was thinking it could be a IIS related issue. However it is windows 8 and through tools like Visual Studios you can run the application locally. Or you can setup IIS to run it locally. Would be nice if in the future they somehow set it up so you can install your application locally through a install package.